# How to initialize controller manually after app has bootstrapped?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-bootstrap

I trying to add angular widgets into an existing non-angular app. The problem is that these widgets are not added by Angular, and are mostly injected into the DOM by a non-angular script.

The first thing I thought was to use `angular.bootstrap` for every widget. But the issue with that approach is that I cannot share services between widgets. So, instead of doing that, I want to bootstrap the Angular app once, and load the controllers manually for each widget.

[Here is a sandbox jsbin where I've been trying stuff without success](http://jsbin.com/jakiw/9/edit)

I'm trying to make `app1` manually and `app2` automatically, while sharing the `sharedThing` service.

Answer (score 0):

In the app config

```
app.config(function($controllerProvider) {
app.register =
    {
        controller: $controllerProvider.register

    };
}
```

then after you declare controller function
`app.register.controller('CtrlName',CntrlFn]);`

Dan had wrote a great article about it. http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx

Comment: I read that article, but it only speaks about how to load controllers dynamically through routing, which is not what I'm trying to do. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found my answer.

I don't know if I had solved it before, but I had to make a call to `$apply` after recompiling the element to see the changes without manually modifying the input. Also, I discovered that I can initialize the angular app with an element outside the DOM and I can compile elements outside the root element! That is perfect for what I'm trying to achieve.

[Anyway, here is the jsBin with the code working.](http://jsbin.com/jakiw/16/edit)